# Sortable table in nativescript (angular2)

Tags: user-interface, angular, nativescript

I want to port a piece of UI I've already coded in an angular2 webapp into a nativescript (angular2) app for android/iphone.

The angular2 web app has a scrollable table with sortable columns and the results in the table can also be filtered via a text input. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

How would you build a scrollable, sortable table like this in nativescript?